# Salesforce Mobile App Rendering in Classic UI

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

We have an Active Login Flow (Type: Flow) through which we send MFA code to the users and verify before allowing them to Home page.

When we try to access our application through Salesforce Mobile App, post login we could see everything rendered in Classic UI theme (desktop feel).

**If we delete the Login Flow and login to Salesforce Mobile App, then everything is rendered in Lightning Experience UI. Anyone know why this is happening?**

[image]